# Navegação usando @RenderBody

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Quando usamos `@RenderBody`, as demais páginas usadas com _Layout, é rendenizado apenas ali dentro, correto?

Minha dúvida é:

Supondo que todas nossas páginas utilizam o `_Layout` que está esse `@RenderBody`

Ao navegar, ele carrega apenas o conteúdo aí dentro ou, ele recarrega o `_Layout` novamente?

Ele recarrega novamente todas os arquivos .js e css encontrados no `_Layout`?

Answer (score 1):

Sim, a página é "montada" inteira no server e enviada como uma página única. Todo conteúdo do `_Layout` e `@RenderBody` é enviado ao cliente a cada requisição. O funcionamento é similar aos includes do php ou do antigo asp.

Pra conseguir esse efeito de página que nunca tem refresh por inteiro você vai precisar de um framework de ***SPA (Single Page Application)*** como *Angular*, *Backbone*, *Ember*.